# Is it possible to use CKEditor in commercial web site?

Tags: fckeditor

I plan to use CKEditor in commercial site. I've read http://ckeditor.com/license but I didn't understand how it is possible to have pricing for commercial use while they offer LGPL(which is good choice for commercial use)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Imagine you want to compile the javascript code of CkEditor into a binary application. Just assume this is possible. Then you would not ship the source code of the library any longer.

If you now even make modifications to the source code to distribute within the binary, you do not satisfy the LGPL as it requires that you provide the source for the library along with your binary. Same for the MPL on the file level.

If you don't want to distribute (your changes in) the source-code form of the library, you then can get a commercial license by the project (you buyout the license).

Next to such specific cases I can imagine that some folks just would like to have a commercial license as form of a backup if their legal department is too much puzzled. If the license is relatively cheap, they can opt for it and continue with their own work w/o being further interrupted. Business, you need to keep it running.

But regarding the LGPL, as long as you offer source (incl. the changes you probably make) of the library, you're fine to use it with non-free programs. So this does not mean that your website must be LGPL it's just using a LGPL'ed library.

Comment: This undersells the difference between LGPL and MPL, I believe. They are not equivalent. Remember that [the MPL is a file-level license](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/400544/61982) and you can rip any file out of the whole and include just it in your app. For that and other reasons, [the MPL is much less "viral"](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/MPL/2.0/FAQ/#virality) than the LGPL imo. Just recall that ckeditor v4 can be licensed under MPL, v5 is GPL or commercial afaict.

Comment: @ruffin: Thanks for your comment, I edited the answer to reflect that it compares with the MPL on the file level. Mind however that the answer is really old, and I don't know any longer for which CKEditor version at that time I had in mind when writing it.

Answer (score 8):

You can use it for your commercial website. However, if you build a product and want to include (distribute) CKEditor with it then you might need a commercial license.

The condition whether you need the license is based on your product's license. If your product is closed sourced then including an open source product with it without sharing the source code is illegal. So, this commercial/closed distribution license fills the gap. You pay for it and you can distribute your product with the CKEditor closed sourced. Additionally you may do any closed source modifications to CKEditor.

TL;DR: if you want to modify and distribute it with a commercial license then you need to pay, otherwise you are free to use to for free!

Comment: Thanks, but how it can be closed source if it is javascript and styles which is open for everyone.

Comment: Yes, the open source version is open for everyone. However, you can create a product which modifies CKEditor to suit your needs. Your options is either to include the modilied source of CKEditor or if you don't want to share the code, the you need to purchase a commercial license. Even if you don't make modifications, the commercial license strips the requirement of providing the source code to the end users.

Comment: @yura: The commercial license of CKEditor (called by them "closed" but that is only a word) offers the source code as well. Closed by CKEditor does not mean, that it's not open source.

Comment: And what about the case when you make a product, but you use CKEditor inisde while not modifying it. Do you still need the closed license?

Comment: @IvayloSlavov: You don't necessarily need the closed license. If you obey the terms of the license then you are fine. In case of a commercial closed source product you'd have to distribute the source of CKEditor which is a bit awkward but valid.

Comment: @Uphill_What'1, Thanks, it seemed quite weird to me, but I'm glad it is fine. Still, I'd prefer to buy that license to be sure I am not violating anything.