# CKEditor 4 - How to set default font?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I use CKEditor 4 and I want to set default font. I added "font_defaultLabel" with my font choice but it doesn't work ...

I found this solution on the Internet but it's a trick for me and not a true solution :

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev ) {
     ev.editor.setData('<span style="font-family:Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;">&shy;</span>');
});
```

Can someone help me?

EpokK

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can use ckeditor's dataprocessor to modify (for example) paragraphs with your choice for font-size, font-family, this will affect any paragraph entered into ckeditor be it pasted, written or changed in the source; something like this:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function( ev ) {
  ev.editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules({
    elements: {
      p: function (e) { e.attributes.style = 'font-size:' + fontsizevariable + 'px; font-family:' + fontfamilyvariable + ';'; }
    }
  });
});
```

same for dataProcessor.dataFilter

But if you intend to view html created outside of your environment, these rules might make it a real mess

Comment: I just want to launch the same command that can be run via the font toolbar.

Comment: Aaaaaand you just saved my day! Inline styles are required for email content to render properly everywhere. It's sad that ckeditor doesn't support this use case well. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

CKeditor uses a default css file for it's content: `contents.css`
You can change the used font(s) there. Just make sure you use the same css (or just the font) when displaying the CKeditor content without CKeditor.

Comment: Yes but if your font family is a variable, how do you do ?

Comment: Where does that variable come from, is it a per user setting or something? Then your solution of setting a font might be the best solution; you'll want to save that font with the input.

Comment: I find it sad that it is not possible to properly configure the font in CKEditor. And when I think that this object is not free ... Finally this is another story.

Comment: I guess setting the default font to a variable is just not needed in 99% of the cases. Also CKeditor is free to use: http://ckeditor.com/about/license, maybe you mean CKfinder or another of their products?

Comment: CKEditor isn't free for business use. I need to set font-family to each initialization of the editor. I use this object for a webmail.

Comment: It IS free actually for commercial use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305276/is-it-possible-to-use-ckeditor-in-commercial-web-site but if you want to make changes to the source that you don't share or just want to use a commercial license that's fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Simply place this below your original CKEDITOR JS, and change the font-size to whatever you like. This works for me, hope it does for you!

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev ) {
 ev.editor.setData('<span style="font-size:48px;">&shy;</span>');
});
```