# How to set default font in CKEditor 4?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to set default font family "Arial" in the CKeditor 4. The below changes have been done. But not working.

In config.js,

```
config.defaultFontLabel = "Arial";
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CKEditor 4 - How to set default font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339258/ckeditor-4-how-to-set-default-font)

Comment: I already tried this. But not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own css files and put the styles for the editor in there. So create a stylesheet called `MyStyle.css` and put this in there. Then save it somewhere, perhaps in the same location as the CKEditor files.

```
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: red;
}
```

Then put the following line in the `config.js` and point to the correct path to the css file.

```
config.contentsCss = '/ckeditor/MyStyle.css';
```

Or if you want different styles per instance, use this

```
<textarea id="CKEditor1" class="CKEditor"></textarea>

<script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.CKEditor').each(function () {
        CKEDITOR.replace($(this).prop('id'));

        CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = '/ckeditor/MyStyle.css';
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Now its working.Also we need to clear the browser cache as well.